# Scrolling using offset().top goes to the wrong place

Tags: jquery

I have a page containing two divs - one contains a table and is not a fixed height, the other contains multiple tables and is a fixed height (with auto overflow-y) based on the first div.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tables-container" style="height: 100vh;">
    <div id="outstanding-table">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                    <td>Column 3</td>
                </tr>
                ...more rows...
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                    <td>Column 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div id="overview-tables" style="overflow-y: auto;">
        <h3 id="table-1">Table 1</h3>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                    <td>Column 3</td>
                </tr>
                ...more rows...
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                    <td>Column 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <h3 id="table-2">Table 2</h3>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                    <td>Column 3</td>
                </tr>
                ...more rows...
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                    <td>Column 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <h3 id="table-3">Table 3</h3>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                    <td>Column 3</td>
                </tr>
                ...more rows...
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                    <td>Column 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        ...more tables...
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var overviewTablesHeight = $('#tables-container').innerHeight() - $('#outstanding-table').innerHeight() - 50;
    $('#overview-tables').innerHeight(overviewTablesHeight);

    var timeoutTime = 1000;
    var tableId = getFirstTableId();

    scrollDown();

    function getFirstTableId() {
        var id = 'table-1';
        return id;
    }

    function getNextTableId() {
        var tableIdParts = tableId.split('-');
        var id = tableIdParts[0] + '-' + (parseInt(tableIdParts[1]) + 1);
        return id;
    }

    function scrollDown() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            tableId = getNextTableId();

            var scrollTo = $('#' + tableId).position().top - $('#overview-tables').offset().top;
            console.log($('#' + tableId).offset().top + ' - ' + $('#overview-tables').offset().top + ' = ' + scrollTo);
            scroll(scrollTo);

            var isBottom = $('#overview-tables').scrollTop() + $('#overview-tables').innerHeight() >= $('#overview-tables')[0].scrollHeight;
            if (isBottom) {
                scrollUp();
            }
            else {
                scrollDown();
            }
        }, timeoutTime);
    }

    function scrollUp() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            scroll(0);
            tableId = getFirstTableId();
            scrollDown();
        }, timeoutTime);
    }

    function scroll(scrollTopValue) {
        $('#overview-tables').animate({ scrollTop: scrollTopValue }, 'fast');
    }
});
```

I'm trying to get the bottom section to automatically scroll down to each `h3` in turn (using the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19012631/3105807)) until it reaches the bottom, at which point it will scroll back to the top and start again. However, `offset().top` doesn't seem to be giving the correct values. For example, the third table will have a lower offset value than the second, causing it to scroll up a bit, instead of down.

Here is a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/2HTHoLujna) to show the problem. I've added console logs so you can see the values being calculated.

---

I've already had a look at these questions, but all seem to be talking about checking the margins, images, padding etc, but in my Bootply above I have no margins, plus the incorrect values do not seem to be out by the same amount each time:

- [jQuery offset().top returns wrong value - error with margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277608/jquery-offset-top-returns-wrong-value-error-with-margin)
- [jQuery offset is not calculating correctly on some pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812211/jquery-offset-is-not-calculating-correctly-on-some-pages)
- [jQuery offset top doesn't work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087670/jquery-offset-top-doesnt-work-correctly)
- [jquery inconsistent positioning using offset().top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744431/jquery-inconsistent-positioning-using-offset-top)
- [.offset().top returning the wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286877/offset-top-returning-the-wrong-value)
- [Jquery scrollTop goes to the wrong position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997229/jquery-scrolltop-goes-to-the-wrong-position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21336546/3105807) which almost fixed my scroll problem, however I had to add a bit extra for it to work correctly in my situation. This is my updated scrollDown function:

```
function scrollDown() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        tableId = getNextTableId();

        var scrollTo = $('#' + tableId).position().top + $('#overview-tables').scrollTop() - $('#outstanding-table').innerHeight();
        scroll(scrollTo);

        var isBottom = $('#overview-tables').scrollTop() + $('#overview-tables').innerHeight() >= $('#overview-tables')[0].scrollHeight;
        if (isBottom) {
            scrollUp();
        }
        else {
            scrollDown();
        }
    }, timeoutTime);
}
```